# UtilityProcess in electron using typescript throws "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, spawn

I'm trying to start a background process in Electrons main process for running heavy socket operations without blocking main. Before I used to do this in a hidden windows renderer.

But I read that it is now recommended to do this in a child process spawn from main process.

I'm having a hard time making it work with typescript in the script file.
I'm using electron react boilerplate as App foundation in newest version.

Here's the code that i use to run the background script:

```
const electronProcess = UtilityProcess.fork('backgroundScript.ts', [
    'ts-node',
    '--esModuleInterop'
], {
    detached: true,
    stdio: 'ignore'
});

// Start the child process
electronProcess.start();
```

When it starts it throws: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

The backgroundscript.ts file until now just contains a simple import statement of a dgram package

As seen in the code example I have tried to set ts-node with argument --esModuleInterop to enable module imports, but it does not work.

Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I found this article which describes how to build the utility files into a node module which can be referenced when starting the utility process. Even if I'm not using Forge, it helped me tweak Webpack to build the code into a seperate node module.

Here's the article https://pradyothkukkapalli.com/tech/electron-utility-process/

But this approach brings some new challenges into your development work, because hot reload does not work, if the utility process code is changed. So this needs to be concidered when choosing to spawn a utility process from main instead of using a hidden renderer/window which works with hot reload.